# What is the XP limit in squad mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

There is most definitely an XP limit in Squad Mode. But does anyone know what the limit is? I don't ever seem to be able to go more than a level up at a time.

Comment: 2000xp for something like safegaurd or recruit difficulty, and it should be 4000xp for regular vs ai. The game tells you when the xp cap is reached, past level 6ish its not an effective way of levelling at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/703505-call-of-duty-ghosts/67745126) forum post the XP limit for Squad Mode is 2100 XP per character.

This is verified on the [Call of Duty Wikia page](https://callofduty.fandom.com/wiki/XP)

> In Squads, XP is earned like it is in multiplayer but there is a point cap of 2,100 XP per match (this cap is doubled during Double XP events).

Answer (score 0):

Around 2000xp per game and you gain a care package once you reach the limit

Comment: Any sources? Can you be any more specific?